# Why is it clic and not clique?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, palabras-raras, rae, interjecciones

I wonder: is "clic", as in "mouse click", the official term that RAE suggests?

Won't the "clique" be a more proper word according to the rules of Spanish? Why hasn't it been chosen instead?

Comment: Because it is not French, in terms of the noun.

Comment: @Lambie no language in the world is French, except French itself

Comment: I think you missed the joke. The answer below is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

"[Clic](https://dle.rae.es/clic)" is an onomatopoeia that sounds exactly as the English "click". In Spanish it's only a noun.

"Clique" is pronounced in Spanish as "*'kli ke*", with a clear Spanish "e" sound at the end, so it would be a bad onomatopoeia.

However, "clique" is a subjunctive or imperative form of the verb "[clicar](https://dle.rae.es/clicar)" (to click). For example, "*cuando el usuario clique en el botón, se emitirá un sonido*" (subjunctive) or "*clique en el botón rojo para terminar*" (imperative).

Comment: why do you assume that onomatopoeia has to match  the original language precisely?  If it was so, Spanish would become English

Comment: Why is in Spanish it's `parque` instead of `park` or `parc` then? If you claim that because of onomatopoeia the words have to match each other in terms of sound

Comment: Why is it `plasticO` instead of `plastic`?  Again -  if you claim that because of onomatopoeia the words have to match each other in terms of sound

Comment: No, an onomatopoeia is a word whose pronunciation matches a sound. Both "clic" and "click" are pronounced the same because both are similar to the sound of a computer mouse when you press one of its buttons. "Quiquiriquí" and "Cockadoodledoo" are also onomatopoeias, but they are very different (probably roosters speak different languages around the world, contrary to computer mice).

Comment: Neither "parque" nor "park" are onomatopoeias. Do parks make a "park" sound? Both come from the French "parc".

Comment: The same for "plástico" and "plastic". Objects made of plastic make all kinds of sounds, so no onomatopoeia here. The term comes from the Latin plastĭcus, in turn from the Greek πλαστικός (plastikós), related to modelling wax or clay.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141416/discussion-on-answer-by-aerobiomat-why-is-it-clic-and-not-clique).

Comment: My question hasn't been answered

Comment: What shitty dog has removed my comments about onomatopoeia? Why the same shitty dog hasn't removed the comments of aerobiomat?

Comment: `"Quiquiriquí" and "Cockadoodledoo" are also onomatopoeias, but they are very different` --> how are they different? And why do you think so? And they contradict your assumption.

Comment: Agreed! You are saying e Exactly what I explained in prevous comments.